# Meaning of the concept of external parameters in Statistical Mechanics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian

I'm confused about the meaning of the concept of *external parameter* in Statistical Mechanics. According to my textbook, the Hamiltonian of a system is a function that depends on the generalized coordinates $\{q_i\}$, the generalized moments $\{p_i\}$ and the external parameters $\{X_\alpha\}$,

$$H=H \big(\{q_i\}, \{p_i\}, \{X_\alpha\}\big)$$

These external parameters are related to the *generalized forces* $\{Y_\alpha\}$, and the thermodynamical work can be expressed through them as

$$\delta W=\overline{\space Y}_{\alpha} d X_{\alpha}$$

What would be the physical meaning of this *external parameter* (and, by the way, of the *generalized forces*) in the context of Mechanical Statistics?